# How does LLVM translate three address LLVM IR `add` into X86 two address `add`?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

EDIT:

I found the `TwoAddressInstructionPass` pass which handles this problem. Now I'm looking into the implementation.

The `add` of LLVM IR is a three address instruction:

```
%x = add i32 %y %z
```

But X86 `add` is two address:

```
add eax 2
```

It seems that the translation requires some kind of:

```
mov dst src1
add dst src2
```

So i'm curious about how LLVM does it. I looked into `X86InstrArithmetic.td` and found the definition of `ArithBinOp_RF`:

```
multiclass ArithBinOp_RF<bits<8> BaseOpc, bits<8> BaseOpc2, bits<8> BaseOpc4,
                         string mnemonic, Format RegMRM, Format MemMRM,
                         SDNode opnodeflag, SDNode opnode,
                         bit CommutableRR, bit ConvertibleToThreeAddress,
                         bit ConvertibleToThreeAddressRR> {
  let Defs = [EFLAGS] in {
    let Constraints = "$src1 = $dst" in {
      let isCommutable = CommutableRR in {
        let isConvertibleToThreeAddress = ConvertibleToThreeAddressRR in {
          def NAME#8rr  : BinOpRR_RF<BaseOpc, mnemonic, Xi8 , opnodeflag>;
          def NAME#16rr : BinOpRR_RF<BaseOpc, mnemonic, Xi16, opnodeflag>;
          def NAME#32rr : BinOpRR_RF<BaseOpc, mnemonic, Xi32, opnodeflag>;
          def NAME#64rr : BinOpRR_RF<BaseOpc, mnemonic, Xi64, opnodeflag>;
        } // isConvertibleToThreeAddress
      } // isCommutable
```

I suspect that `Constraints` is related to the translation:

1. If that is the case, how does the `Constraints` work?
2. If not, how and where does LLVM handle the translation (except the `lea` case) ? Does it insert `mov`? If that is the case, how does LLVM handle redundant `mov`s?

Comment: Why should LLVM want or need to insert those `mov`s in the first place? Remember that LLVM usess SSA, there is no way to say `%x = add i32 %x %y`.

Comment: @arnt That's the problem I think of. There is no way for LLVM to express `%x = add i32 %x %y` but that's the way to `add` in x86. So my question is how LLVM transforms `%z = add i32 %x %y` into x86 `add dst src`.

Comment: One register contains `%y` up to the add and `%z` after the add. There may not be any register that contains `%y` after the add. `%y` isn't a register, you see, it's a a value, with its own notion of liveness. The register allocator (there are several) may decide to keep it in a register all the time, keep it in two different ones at different locations, read it from memory, whatever.

Comment: @arnt Thanks for the explanation. IIUC, you are talking about the register allocation phrase. But IMO instruction selection comes first, doesn't it? At the selection phrase (which is before register allocation(?)), LLVM selects LLVM IR into x86 machine instructions and my question is how LLVM would select LLVM IR `add`? If the register allocator decides to keep it in a register all the time, as you said, it must emit `mov` instructions... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `TwoAddressInstructionPass`, which translates three-address mode instructions into two-address mode if some of `MachineOperand`s in a `MachineInstr` are tied (TwoAddressInstructionPass.cpp):

```cpp
static bool isTwoAddrUse(MachineInstr &MI, unsigned Reg, unsigned &DstReg) {
  for (unsigned i = 0, NumOps = MI.getNumOperands(); i != NumOps; ++i) {
    const MachineOperand &MO = MI.getOperand(i);
    if (!MO.isReg() || !MO.isUse() || MO.getReg() != Reg)
      continue;
    unsigned ti;
    if (MI.isRegTiedToDefOperand(i, &ti)) {
      DstReg = MI.getOperand(ti).getReg();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

"Tied" means two operands are mapped to the same register. When we write `Constraints = "$src1 = $dst"` in tablegen, generated code would set `$src1` and `$dst` as "tied"  (GlobalISel/Utils.cpp):

```cpp
bool llvm::constrainSelectedInstRegOperands(MachineInstr &I,
                                            const TargetInstrInfo &TII,
                                            const TargetRegisterInfo &TRI,
                                            const RegisterBankInfo &RBI) {
  assert(!isPreISelGenericOpcode(I.getOpcode()) &&
         "A selected instruction is expected");
  MachineBasicBlock &MBB = *I.getParent();
  MachineFunction &MF = *MBB.getParent();
  MachineRegisterInfo &MRI = MF.getRegInfo();

  for (unsigned OpI = 0, OpE = I.getNumExplicitOperands(); OpI != OpE; ++OpI) {
    MachineOperand &MO = I.getOperand(OpI);

    // There's nothing to be done on non-register operands.
    if (!MO.isReg())
      continue;

    LLVM_DEBUG(dbgs() << "Converting operand: " << MO << '\n');
    assert(MO.isReg() && "Unsupported non-reg operand");

    Register Reg = MO.getReg();
    // Physical registers don't need to be constrained.
    if (Register::isPhysicalRegister(Reg))
      continue;

    // Register operands with a value of 0 (e.g. predicate operands) don't need
    // to be constrained.
    if (Reg == 0)
      continue;

    // If the operand is a vreg, we should constrain its regclass, and only
    // insert COPYs if that's impossible.
    // constrainOperandRegClass does that for us.
    MO.setReg(constrainOperandRegClass(MF, TRI, MRI, TII, RBI, I, I.getDesc(),
                                       MO, OpI));

    // Tie uses to defs as indicated in MCInstrDesc if this hasn't already been
    // done.
    if (MO.isUse()) {
      int DefIdx = I.getDesc().getOperandConstraint(OpI, MCOI::TIED_TO);
      if (DefIdx != -1 && !I.isRegTiedToUseOperand(DefIdx))
        I.tieOperands(DefIdx, OpI);
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```